# Check if local time is after midnight in another timezone

Tags: swift, time

I want to check if my local time is after midnight in another time zone.

Specifically, if right now where I am at is 11 PM Saturday, or 1 AM Sunday local time, I want to see if it is the start of a new week in Central Time (after 12 AM Sunday).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Calendar`'s `dateComponents(in: TimeZone, from: Date)` to check the time and date in another timezone. For your specific application:

```
// create current date, central time zone, and get the current calendar
let now = Date()
let centralTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CST")!
let calendar = Calendar.current

let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: centralTimeZone, from: now)

if components.weekday == 1 {
    print("It is Sunday in Central Standard Time.")
} else {
    print("It is not Sunday in Central Standard Time.")
}
```

What you're doing there is asking the current calendar to give you a full set of [DateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponents) in the specified timezone. Then `components.weekday` gives the day of the week as an Int, starting with 1 for Sunday in the Gregorian calendar.

If you want to know more generally if it's "tomorrow" somewhere, here's a simple method:

```
func isItTomorrow(in zone: TimeZone) -> Bool {
    var calendarInZone = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.current.identifier)
    calendarInZone.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CST")!
    return calendarInZone.isDateInTomorrow(Date())
}

if isItTomorrow(in: centralTimeZone) {
    print("It is tomorrow.")
} else {
    print("It is not tomorrow.")
}
```

`isItTomorrow(in: TimeZone)` creates a new calendar of the same type as the current calendar (presumably `.gregorian`, but you never know) and sets its timezone to the desired one. Then it uses the neat built-in `Calendar` method `.isDateInTomorrow()` to check if the current time is "tomorrow" in the target timezone.

There are lots of other ways to do it, and depending on your specific need there may be a built-in method that will save you a lot of work, so it's well worth reading through the docs on [Calendar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar) and [DateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponents) to see what's available.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I'm gonna try and implement it in my app tomorrow!